# How can I get this Bootstrap class HTML elements to get in one single line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a `<select>`, and two `<input type="text">` elements in one single row. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Estudios de Posgrado</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7">

        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="input-group-select form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tituloPosgrado1" placeholder="Título">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->                     

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A" id="Posgrado1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Knowing Bootstrap grid system is 12 units based, I'm giving two units for label, seven for the `select` and one `input` and the 3 left for last `input`.

I want the select and one input to be together, that's why I'm trying to use `.input-group` classes.

However, select it's taking its width throwing last input to next line, how how can fix it?

This is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rC7aj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your div containing the select and the first input in two parts of 6 units each

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Estudios de Posgrado</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select class="input-group-select form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tituloPosgrado1" placeholder="Título">
        </div>                
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A" id="Posgrado1">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9h7k8/

@Diegoaguilar asked for a smaller padding on each div.

```
// HTML
<div class="form-group smallPadding">

    <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Estudios de Posgrado</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select class="input-group-select form-control">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tituloPosgrado1" placeholder="Título">
        </div>                
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A" id="Posgrado1">
    </div>
</div>

// CSS
.smallPadding div{
    padding-right : 2px;
    padding-left : 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9h7k8/2/

Comment: Yeah, I rather did that. Just, how can I tell Bootstrap to reduce that offseft among `.col-xs-X`?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to reduce exactly ?

Comment: Using the code you gave, there's a certain space between elements. How can I reduce that space?

Comment: The 'col-xs-X' classes have 15px of padding on each side. I guess you would have to create a class with the padding you want and add it to your elements as second class. like this for example http://jsfiddle.net/9h7k8/2/

Comment: Great, can you edit the answer so it'll be more illustrative and will help someone else in future?